# Help simplifying function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ and $g(x)=x+8$. Find the domain of the following function then simplify the expression.

$$(f+g)(x)$$

I get that the domain is $[0,\infty)$ but I'm horrible at simplifying, please help.

Comment: Well, what did you get for $(f+g)(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)=\sqrt{x}+x+8$. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 2):

If $\mathrm{f}(x)=\sqrt{x}$ and $\mathrm{g}(x)=x+8$ and you apply point-wise addition, i.e. 
$$(\mathrm{f}+\mathrm{g})(x) := \mathrm{f}(x)+\mathrm{g}(x)$$
then $(\mathrm{f}+\mathrm{g})(x)=\sqrt{x}+x+8$. We need $x \ge 0$ for $(\mathrm{f}+\mathrm{g})(x)$ to be real. As you say: the domain of $\mathrm{f}+\mathrm{g}$ is $[0,\infty)$. As for simplification, well, there isn't really much that you can do with that.

You see to already have the correct answer.